# Is there an RStudio plugin to view Jupyter notebooks (.ipynb)?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, rstudio

I am collaborating on a project where some of the other data scientists like to create Jupyter notebooks. I'm an R/RStudio man myself, but I have to use VSCode on this project because it renders notebooks nicely in the editor. Is there a plugin for RStudio that will format `.ipynb` files the way that Jupyter Notebooks does, allowing me to at least read the notebooks in RStudio?

I am not interested in the drama that would ensue from converting the `.ipynb` files to Quarto.

Just to clarify: I want to continue using RStudio as my IDE, and I want to be able to open a `.ipynb` file within RStudio.

Comment: I've never heard about a RStudio plugin to view inside it Jupyter notebooks. But to share the views of Jupyter notebooks with my users I've installed Jupyter Hub (https://jupyter.org/hub) on a Linux server : "A multi-user version of the notebook designed for companies, classrooms and research labs".

Comment: You can also use in Jupyter the menu "File/Save and Export Notebook As…" to HTML for example.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Actually, I want to keep using RStudio as my IDE, and to open the `.ipynb` files within RStudio.

Comment: I understood well that, but I think it's not possible. Read this 2 links [github/rstudio #3021: Support for Jupyter notebooks in RStudio](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3021) and [github/mwouts/jupytext #1](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/issues/1) and, if you want, open a feature request or question at [https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/new/choose](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/new/choose).

Comment: "I am not interested in the drama that would ensue from converting the .ipynb files to Quarto." -- Looks like Hamel Husain already handled that: [nbsnanity: Like nbviewer, but uses Quarto as the renderer.](https://github.com/hamelsmu/nbsanity). You can try it using notebooks without installing anything at [nbsanity.com](https://nbsanity.com/). From developer, "... it uses @quarto_pub as the renderer, which has a more sane way of showing notebooks on different platforms. The upshot is, it will also respect all the quarto directives if that happens to be in your notebook"

Comment: @Wayne this is the closest I've seen to a solution. Unfortunately, it looks like nbsanity will only render in the browser - I was looking for a way to render the notebook in RStudio. Probably nbsanity (or nbviewer) could be adapted into an RStudio plugin, since the RStudio interface is drawn by Electron. A project for the next time I have free time, perhaps.